# I am trying to calculate the execution time for my code

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the execution time for my code in milliseconds but when i run it there is no any results as well no error I don't know where is the problem exactly although as I mentioned before there is no any errors  . please help

here is my piece of code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std ;
#include<time.h>

class sort{

public:


    int read_file()
    {
    int x ; 
    char filename[50];
    ifstream numbersfile ;
    cout<<"Please enter the file name below"<<endl<<"_______________________________________________"<<endl;
    cin.getline(filename,50);
    cout<<"_______________________________________________"<<endl;
    numbersfile.open(filename);
    if(!numbersfile.is_open()){
        cout<<"Failed to load requierd file"<<endl;
    return 0 ;
    }
    int arr[13];
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    cout<<"The elements supposed to be sorted are:"<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i =0;i<13;i++){
        numbersfile>>arr[i];
        cout<<arr[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------";
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    counting_sort(arr,n);

    }


    int counting_sort(int arr[],int size)
        {

    int n=size;
    int max=arr[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        if (arr[i]>max) { 
            max=arr[i];
        }
    }

    int *output_array=new int[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        output_array[i]=0;
    }
    int *count=new int[max+1];
    for (int i=0;i<=max+1;i++) {
        count[i]=0;

    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        count[arr[i]]=count[arr[i]]+1;
    }
    for (int i=1;i<max+1;i++) {
        count[i]=count[i]+count[i-1];
    }
    for (int  i=n-1;i>=1;i--) {
        output_array[count[arr[i]]-1]=arr[i];
        count[arr[i]]=count[arr[i]]-1;
    }

    cout<<"The sorted elements are:"<<endl<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout<<output_array[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    return 0;
}




};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     clock_t Start_Time = clock();
    sort s1;
    s1.read_file();

    return 0;

    cout <<"The time taken to execute this process is:\n"<< double( clock() - Start_Time ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " seconds." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger then step through your code, inspecting the variables as you do so.

Comment: Try printing before returning from `main`.

Comment: What if I want to open a file with more than 49 characters? Why not use `std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

Your `cout` statement in main is after your return statement.  This means that that line of code will never run since the program has already returned.  You can swap those two lines and you will get your output.

Comment: a millisecond is a thousandth of a second so to convert seconds to milliseconds you need to multiply your result by 1000.

Comment: i want a help also please